# Android crashes when try to overwrite TextViews

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout

I've created a timetable app, which allows the user to enter data and then view it.However if the user enters an entry, on a day and time where there already is one, my emulator crashes(forces a close).
Basically I'm pulling back data to a linear layout- which contains 10 TextViews, each representing the times 9-15.
Here's the code:

```
        public void addMondayGrid() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int index = 0; index < info.mon.size(); index++) {

        // int entryId = info.monIds.get(index);
        int time = info.monTimes.get(index);
        int id = info.monIds.get(index);
        int duration = info.monDuration.get(index);
        String dayOfWeek = "mon";

        timeId = getResources().getIdentifier("mon" + time, "id",
                getPackageName());
        if (duration == 1) {
            SpannableString text = new    SpannableString(info.mon.get(index));
            setEntryColour(text);
            final TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(timeId);
            textV.setTextSize(10);
            textV.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            textV.setId(id);
            deleteGridEntry(textV);
        } else {
            longerDuration(time, index, id, info.mon, dayOfWeek);

        }

    }

}
```

The thing is is works fine as long as there isn't two entries for the same day and time, eg. monday at 9 oclock.
Anyone have any ideas?I'm quite new to this and any help would be much appreciated!

I have to reference the id this way as there are too many ids to reference any other way,is there not a simple way to overwrite the old textView with new data pulled back from the database? I want the id to be the same one as that is the textView I want to deal with, but it just keeps crashing, is it something to do with instances?

Comment: Make sure timeId and textV are as expected and non-null

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
      final TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(timeId);
```

to:

```
        final TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeId);
```

Comment: I defined all my ids in my xml file as mon9,mon10,tue12 etc(I know bad coding)and then the variable timeid makes sure the text is set in the correct textView,any other ideas?

Comment: you need to know how to reference xml values. try reading this: [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)